# What is the unchecked value for a checkbox in html?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to determine on page load if a checkbox should be checked or not. I have tried setting checked to false but that just says it's an invalid value. I have also tried using a hidden field and setting that to the php value and on window.load setting the checkbox value but for some reason that didn't work either. I am looking for a simple way to do this.

```
$customer = Customer::getCustomer($id);

$isChecked = "checked";

if ($customer->isactive) {
$isChecked = "unchecked";
}

<input type="checkbox" value="Active" checked="<?=$isChecked?>" />
```

Is it really this difficult in html to uncheck a checkbox?

Comment: it's a simple binary relationship.  on or off.  If it is checked, it would be set, otherwise it is not set.

Comment: Can you clarify a little?  Are you getting the checked value from your database, and having trouble allowing users to uncheck it?

Comment: Ok how do I edit my question here?

Comment: click on "edit" just beneath your question.

Answer (score 2):

Unchecked is the default state of the checkbox so you dont need to add anything:

**Unchecked:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Active" />
```

**Checked:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Active" checked="checked" />
```

or you don't even need to do this `="checked"`

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Active" checked />
```

is enough too (:

So comming back to you example you could do:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Active" checked="<?php echo ($customer->isactive) ? '' : 'checked'; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ACTUAL_VALUE" checked><!-- Will be posted unless manually unchecked by the user -->
```

You need to only put 'checked' if it is actually checked. This input won't be posted to the server on form submit if it is not checked.

For unchecked it is simply:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ACTUAL_VALUE"> <!-- Won't be posted unless checked by the user -->
```

**Based on your comments I would do something like this, using a ternary operator:**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="ACTUAL_VALUE" <?php echo $customer->isactive ? 'checked' : '';?>>
```

Comment: Okay so apparently I can't line break when responding to a comment here. I just signed up for this forum and don't know how to line break. That's just odd. Enter submits the comment rather than adding a page break.

Comment: You had the right idea. If i am not using a framework I usually use a ternary operator inline, in the input element, which saves a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the only way I can edit my question or add additional info. Wow...

Look enter now adds a line break yay!!

Okay I am getting the value from my database of whether or not it's active and should be checked or unchecked depending on that value. I guess I could do it this way.

```
<?php 
if ($customer->isactive) {
?> <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<?php } else { ?> 
<input type="checkbox" /> <?php } ?>
```

I know leaving it blank won't check it but that won't work because I have to have the checked= part in case it should be checked unless there is a way to add checked="checked" if the customer is active and not add anything if it isn't active.

Comment: you can edit your original question, by clicking on edit just below it.  See those small gray links, labled "share edit close delete flag".  it's just below your question, on the left

Comment: Thank you, usually greyed out links mean you can't click on them so I just glanced right over them. How do you add a line break in a comment?

Comment: that you unfortunately can't do.

Comment: I recommend editing your original question, and then deleting this "answer" or it may be flagged

Comment: I recommend reading through the help files on the site;  they will make things clearer